# Add multiple values to text area

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, invoice

I'm creating an invoice and I'm trying to make multiple values  go into the text area I created.

The textarea looks like this

```
<textarea input type ="text" name = "textarea" id = "textarea" rows = "12" cols = "180" placeholder = "--Item Code--  --Item Name--   --Item Cost-- --Quantity--  --Subtotal--  --Tax--  --Total--"></textarea>
```

I also have a button called

```
<div id="AddItemButton">
            <td align = "left"><input type="button" value= "Add Item" id = "add" onclick="computeCost();"/>
            </td> 
        </div>
```

I concatenated the values I want to go into the textarea  `'document.getElementById'`

```
document.getElementById('textarea').value = ("\n")+("\n") + "--" + code + "--" + " " + " " + "--Item Name--" + "--" +  itemName + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + cost +"--" + " " + " " + "--" + quantity + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + subtotal + "--" + " " + " " + " " + "--" + tax + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + total + "--";
```

total, subtotal, tax etc. are all being displayed in the text area.  The problem I'm having is that every time I hit "add item" it replaces the old values. I'd like for it to add the new values to the text area while saving the old ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then use `+=` when inserting the values:

```
document.getElementById('textarea').value += ("\n")+("\n") + "--" + code + "--" + " " + " " + "--Item Name--" + "--" +  itemName + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + cost +"--" + " " + " " + "--" + quantity + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + subtotal + "--" + " " + " " + " " + "--" + tax + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + total + "--";
```

It'll take the current `value` - and add the new items to it.

Comment: Darn...you beat me to it. :)

Comment: @tymeJV, There is one little thing I'm running into now.  It's putting the values in the text area, but it's not adding them.   So if the first value is 300 and the second is 200, the total on the bottom isn't = 500, it's equaling 200.  I tried to += total, tax and subtotal but it gave me results that were way too high

Comment: @E.Maggini I'm getting multiple values in the text area, but it's not calculating the sum of all the values I enter.

Comment: If you could create a fiddle of the current state of your code, I'll take a stab at it.